# Selector for class and all children of it

Tags: html, css

I have the following

```
<label class="noblock">
  <input> ...
  ...
</label>
```

I want to specify the CSS `display: inline` for the class `noblock` as well as all children of it (anything inside it). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: FYI, "children" are only the first "level" of descendants (just like children in real life). "Anything inside it" would be just "descendants"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
.noblock, .noblock * {
    display: inline;
}
```

Or if you want to target only direct descendants:

```
.noblock, .noblock > * {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
label.noblock, label.noblock * { display: inline }
```

The `*` used here to select all **descendants** inside any `label` element with class `noblock`

Answer (score 0):

```
.noblock, .noblock * {
    display: inline;
}
```

Notice it would be better to replace `*` by something else (`input` for example if every child is this kind of element)